# acronym package: acronym (fulltext)

Tags: acronyms

I'm looking for a way to use the acronym package a little different:

normal:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{acronym}

\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{snrk}[SnRK]{Sucrose non-fermenting Receptor Kinase}
\end{acronym}
The \ac{snrk}2.2 is very important in signalling...
\end{document}
```

normal result:
The Sucrose non-fermenting Receptor Kinase (SnRK)2.2 is very important in signalling...

__

what I want:

The SnRK2.2 (Sucrose non-fermenting Receptor Kinase) is very important in signalling...

__

Does anyone knows a way how to realize this?
Thanks to everyone!

Comment: please complete your MWE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following code to your preamble after loading the acronym package:

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@acf[1]{%
    \acffont{%
        \AC@acs{#1}%
        \nolinebreak[3]%
        \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}})}%
    }%
  \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi
}
\makeatother
```

The full code:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{acronym}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\@acf[1]{%
    \acffont{%
        \AC@acs{#1}%
        \nolinebreak[3]%
        \acfsfont{(\acsfont{\AC@placelabel{#1}\AC@acl{#1}})}%
    }%
  \ifAC@starred\else\AC@logged{#1}\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{acronym}
    \acro{myacronym}[short]{Long long long}
\end{acronym}

\ac{myacronym}, \ac{myacronym}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `\acf{YOUR ACRONYM}`. It prints out the whole acronym aka the long version. https://github.com/oetiker/acronym/blob/master/acronym.dtx L215